# Is it allowed to use Boolean operators when initializing scalar variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, initialization, boolean

For example, could I write something like:

`my $var = "A" || "B";`

where `($var eq "A")` and `($var eq "B")` would both evaluate to true? If not, is there some way around this?

Comment: Why would you want that? What should `print $var` output in such case?

Comment: I think you want to use hash, so `if ($var eq "A")` should translate to `if ($var{A})`

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for [Quantum::Superpositions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Quantum::Superpositions)?

**Update:** An example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Quantum::Superpositions;

my $var = any('A', 'B', 'C');

for ('A', 'B') {
  if ($var eq $_) {
    say "\$var equals $_";
  } else {
    say "\$var doesn't equal $_";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$var equals A
$var equals B
$var doesn't equal C
```

Comment: Of all the modules I've never found a practical use for, Quantum::Superpositions has always been my favorite.

Comment: I think you need to include an example. This is pretty weird stuff. :)

Comment: @simbabque: Good idea. Done :-)

Comment: Wow! I'd never noticed this module before. How bizarre. Good call for an answer though, but on the face of it I would use `my $var = { A => 1, B => 1}` and `if ( $var->{$_} )`

Comment: @DaveCross Interesting! Thanks for the example.

Comment: @Borodin: Were you not in the Perl community in the early 2000s when Damian Conway was giving his Quantum Superpositions talk to any Perl Monger group that would listen? :-)

Comment: @DaveCross: I did see his 2016 YAPC talk [***On The Shoulders Of Giants***](http://youtu.be/Nq2HkAYbG5o) which is an excellent run through of Perl 6 where he talks about nondeterminism and quantum computing as a way of checking for prime numbers, but I had no idea he was into such stuff so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
From what I've gathered from your comments and previous question you have a string with chars and just want to check if one char is inside of it. Instead of constructing something like `$var = "A" || "B"` (which doesn't work) you can simply check if the needed char is in the string (with a simple regex):

```
$var = "AB";
if ($var =~ /A/) { # True
    # Calculations
}
if ($var =~ /B/) { # Also true
    # Other calculations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It sounds like you misunderstand logical operator and bitwise operator.

**|** is bitwise operator, it works on bits.

**||** is logical operator

From what you say, I presume you need logical operator, but be more specific.

You can get some help there: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355